# what's the type of expression (n `mod` 2 == 0)

Tags: haskell, type-signature

From my lecture, I learn that the type of the expression `` (n `mod` 2 == 0) `` is `Int -> Bool` why it is not `Int -> Int -> Bool` ?

`` n `mod` 2 `` has the type `(Int -> Int)` and if we write `` n `mod` 2 `` in the form `g = h(n)` then `` (n `mod` 2 == 0) `` can be write as  `g(m)` which has the type `Int -> Bool`
In the end isn't it shall be the type (`Int -> Int -> Bool`)?

Comment: Why do you believe ```n `mod` 2 == 0``` has the type `Int -> Bool`? (It doesn't.) What does "write ```n `mod` 2``` in the form `g = h(n)`" mean? Why would `g(m)` be equivalent to another expression like ```(n `mod` 2 == 0)``` that doesn't mention `m`? It is difficult to correct your thinking mistakes at the moment, because there's clearly an important one but you haven't given us enough details about your thought process to identify what it is.

Comment: You misunderstood something in the lecture. ``n `mod` 2 == 0`` has type `Bool`, as ``n `mod` 2`` and `0` both have type `Int`, and the comparison of the two produces either `True` or `False`. `mod` itself (ignoring parametricity) has type `Int -> Int -> Int`; it takes two `Int` values (`n` and `2` in your example) and returns an `Int` result.

Comment: It actually has type `Bool`, it is only if `n` is a parameter, so ``\n -> n `mod` 2 == 0`` that it has as type `Integral a => a -> Bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` (n `mod` 2 == 0) `` has as type `Bool`, indeed, the expression is equivalent to `(==) (mod n 2) 0` and since [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) returns a `Bool` if it uses two parameters, this thus means that `` (n `mod` 2 == 0) `` has as type `Bool`. This will require that there is variable named `n` that is in scope and that `n` need to have as type `n :: Integral a => a`, so a value of a type that is a member of the [**`Integral`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral). It also means that `mod n 2` and `0` both have to be of the same type, and that type is a member of the [**`Eq`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq).

If you construct a function with `n` as parameter, like `\n -> n mod 2 == 0` then it has as type `Integral a => a -> Bool`, or you can further specialize that to `Int -> Bool`, since it is a function that maps a parameter `n` of type `Integral a => a` or specialized as `Int` to a `Bool`.

For the same reason it is not `Int -> Int -> Bool`: it takes no parameters, and the `` (n `mod` 2 == 0) `` itself is an expression that evaluates to a `Bool`, hence its type is `Bool`. If you would have constructed a function, like `` \n -> \m -> n `mod` 2 == 0 ``, its type was `Integral a => a -> (b -> Bool)` or less verbose `Integral a => a -> b -> Bool`. Here `m` can be a value of any type, and its value does not matter for the result of the function. It is thus just an "ad hoc" variable used to make this a function that takes two parameters.

The same holds for `` n `mod` 2 ``: a more canonical form of this expression is `mod n 2`, since `mod` has type [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) is an expression of type `Integral a => a`. This type is the same as the type for `n` and `2`. If we make a function with `n` the parameter, so `\n -> n mod 2`, then the type of this function is `Integral a => a -> a`. The type can be *specialized* to `Int -> Int`, since `Int` is a member of the `Integral` typeclass.

Answer (score -2):

It comes from typing rules. Haskell has bit more rules than given below, but you can start with these.
[image: typing rules]

The rule (3) is the only one that constructs a function. Your expression forms from (1,2,4).

If you need further help with these rules, put a comment.

Comment: :( I understand none of them, not even the first one. Can you give me some reference. I need to read a lot.

Comment: The image is from simply typed lambda calculus on Wikipedia.

Comment: To read these: The thing above the line can turn into a thing below the line. Next read the T turned side ways. On the left side symbol denote free variables. On the right side you got the term that's building up. The rules are visually stacked with each other to form clauses like (mod n 2).

Comment: Throwing a bunch of formal type theory at someone who thinks a Boolean expression has a function type isn't going to be helpful.